# Continuous ping with hourly reports

Tags: windows, networking, cmd, ping

In cmd, is there any way to create a normal continuous ping and automatically save the ping result every one hour?

Actually i want to use the normal ping result to be analyzed in excel sheet. Most of the tools out there will summarize the report, thus i cant get the average, iqr, median, 70th and 90th percentile of the ping.

Comment: Are you looking for how many pings fail, or what are you looking for? There are better tools for something like that, e.g. IP SLA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. Create a batch file which will split the ping output line with delimiters *Space, Equal, Less*, and use 7th token if 8th token is "TTL".
Then schedule the batch to run once in an hour.

```
SET IP=google.com
SET RESPONSE=timeout
FOR /F "tokens=1-9 delims==< " %%a IN ('PING -n 1 -w 2500 %IP%') DO IF "%%h"=="TTL" SET RESPONSE=%%g
ECHO %DATE% %TIME% %IP% %RESPONSE% >>%IP%.log
```